# Make feature vector of words in documents using bag of word model

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, feature-extraction

I am trying to implement BoW model for which I need BoW feature vector. I have several train folders which contain several text files. I created the vocab of the whole training data. I now pass the whole vocabulary and document one by one. But I don't know how to proceed. I followed one source and implemented this code:

```
corpus = dict(((term, index) for index, term in    enumerate(sorted(total_vocab)))
fvs = [[0]*num_words for _ in input]
print(fvs)
for i, doc_terms in enumerate(input):
    fv = fvs[i]
    for term in doc_terms:
        fv[corpus[term]] += 1
```

It gives me some 90,000 sized vector with all zeros.

What should I do in order to get the feature vector?

Here is the snippet of the class:

```
 class FeatureVector(object):
        def __init__(self,vocabsize,numdata):
                self.vocabsize = vocabsize
                self.X =  np.zeros((numdata,self.vocabsize), dtype=np.int)
                self.Y =  np.zeros((numdata,), dtype=np.int)

        def make_featurevector(self, input, classid,total_vocab):
                corpus = dict(((term, index) for index, term in enumerate(sorted(total_vocab)))
                #fvs = [[0]*num_words for _ in input]
                #print(fvs)
                #for i, doc_terms in enumerate(input):
                    #fv = fvs[i]
                    #for term in doc_terms:
                        #fv[corpus[term]] += 1
                #var = np.zeros((len(total_vocab),1),dtype=np.int)
                #for raw_word in input:
                  #  for eachkey in total_vocab.keys():
                   #    if eachkey in raw_word:
                    #       var[raw_word] += 1
                #print fvs
                """
                Takes input tihe documents and outputs the feature vectors as X and classids as Y.
                """
```

Comment: remove unnecessary quotes

Comment: The vectors are not all zeroes. There are non-zero values at the positions that correspond to words that are found in the input document.